# How to unlock environment in R?

Tags: r, locking

Playing with Binding and Environment Adjustments in R , we have this 3 functions:

1. `lockEnvironment(env)` locks env so you can't add a new symbol to env.
2. `lockBinding(sym, env)` locks the sym within env so you can't modfiy it
3. `unlockBinding(sym, env)` relax the latter lock.

But how can I Unlock the environment? Maybe I miss something but it looks like R don't expose an `unlockEnvironment` function or equivalent mechanism to unlock the env ? Is there some design reason to this?

Here an example of how to use this functions:

```
e <- new.env()
lockEnvironment(e)
get("x",e)
assign("x",2,envir=e)
lockBinding("x", e)
get("x",e)
unlockBinding("x", e)
assign("x",3,envir=e)

## how to relese e lock?
unlockEnvironment(e) ## the function doesn't exist
```

Comment: I see neither a robust answer nor any apparent addition of `unlockEnvironment()` as of at least R-3.5.1. Have you found any resolution or explanation?

Comment: see also https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369#file-unlockenvironment-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910778/unlockenvironment-implemented-via-rcpp-instead-of-inline/25922051#25922051

Answer (score 4):

I think the best you can do is make a new unlocked environment.  You could either copy all the fields, or make the existing one a parent of the new one.  That means all the existing variables get inherited.

```
unlockEnvironment <- function (env) {
  return (new.env(parent=env))
}

e <- unlockEnvironment(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The {rlang} package provides [`env_unlock()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_unlock.html) for development usage:

```
rlang::env_unlock(env)
```