# How to unlockEnvironment in R - error

Tags: r, environment

I'd like to lock an environment (and bindings) to make sure some data cannot be accidentially corrupted during execution of further code. Later, I'd need to unlock it again. There was this wonderful post [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132492/how-to-unlock-environment-in-r) pointing to [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369) quite some time ago (this is why I created a new post) demonstrating a way to unlockEnvironment, however now it throws just an error (R version 3.0.1):

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.1/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file3e30b45254d.cpp 2> file3e30b45254d.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25922051/5977215) is possibly what you're after?