# 'unlockEnvironment' implemented via 'Rcpp' instead of 'inline'

Tags: c++, c, r, inline, rcpp

### Actual question

Could someone get me started on what I need to do to implement the code of `unlockEnvironment` below in [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)?

### Background

Came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132492/how-to-unlock-environment-in-r) and tried Winston Chang's solution based on C code with [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html). It works, but I have the feeling I know too little (practically nothing, that is) about either inline or C/C++ to really know what I'm doing ;-)

So I thought this would be a great opportunity to finally start learning on how to use R as an interface to C and C++. And I think I'd like to hopp on the [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) train for doing so!

### The code from Winston's [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wch/3280369#file-unlockenvironment-r)

```
require("inline")

inc <- '
/* This is taken from envir.c in the R 2.15.1 source
https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/main/envir.c
*/
#define FRAME_LOCK_MASK (1<<14)
#define FRAME_IS_LOCKED(e) (ENVFLAGS(e) & FRAME_LOCK_MASK)
#define UNLOCK_FRAME(e) SET_ENVFLAGS(e, ENVFLAGS(e) & (~ FRAME_LOCK_MASK))
'
src <- '
if (TYPEOF(env) == NILSXP)
error("use of NULL environment is defunct");
if (TYPEOF(env) != ENVSXP)
error("not an environment");

UNLOCK_FRAME(env);

// Return TRUE if unlocked; FALSE otherwise
SEXP result = PROTECT( Rf_allocVector(LGLSXP, 1) );
LOGICAL(result)[0] = FRAME_IS_LOCKED(env) == 0;
UNPROTECT(1);

return result;
'
unlockEnvironment <- inline::cfunction(
  signature(env = "environment"),
  includes = inc,
  body = src
)
```

### Refactoring error

On a side note: I ran into an error with Winston's code when I organize it in a certain way in the `/R` directory of my package project:

Using S4 methods most of the time, I tried to factor Winston's code out into a standard R function `.unlockEnvironment()` that I put into the file `/R/.unlockEnvironment.r`

I then would create my S4 methods for `unlockEnvironment()` in `/R/unlockEnvironment.r`. The method with signature `env:environment` would then simply call `.unlockEnvironment(env = env)`.

Setting up things that way, I end up with the following error:

> > Error in .Primitive(".Call")(, env) : 
> >       NULL value passed as symbol address

If I put the code in `/R/.unlockEnvironment.r` directory with in the respective method in `/R/unlockEnvironment.r` (thus re-sourcing the inline code each time the respective method of `unlockEnvironment()` is called), everything works just fine - but it's very inefficient because of the repeated re-sourcing.

So I guess this must have either something to do with the way the C code is written or with the way you need to organize your C-based functions when using [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html)?

Comment: I do not understand what you want from Rcpp here.  R has a C API, and Winston's code uses it.  We can write the same code to be called from Rcpp via Rcpp Attributes but it _remains of course C code talking to the same C API_. Whether or not that works for you has more to do the with C API and what you can or cannot do with environment -- rather than whether or you not involve Rcpp to build it.  So not an Rcpp question AFAICT.

Comment: It's not that I want to get *rid* of the C-code, quite the opposite! I just thought this would maybe be an "easy enough for me to grasp" example to see how the same thing is done by using `Rcpp` instead of `inline` as I want to learn how to use R as an interface to C++. I'm indifferent with respect to the code either remaining C-code or it being translated to C++ code. Sorry if this seems like a stupid noob question, but I don't know my way around C/C++ yet ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your question basically amounts to, 'how do I use `Rcpp::attributes`'? And I would suggest that you go over many of the examples in the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/) to learn a bit more.

The main idea: write some C++ code, put it a `.cpp` file, then call `Rcpp::sourceCpp(<file>)` to load it. For this particular example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

/* This is taken from envir.c in the R 2.15.1 source
https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/main/envir.c
*/
#define FRAME_LOCK_MASK (1<<14)
#define FRAME_IS_LOCKED(e) (ENVFLAGS(e) & FRAME_LOCK_MASK)
#define UNLOCK_FRAME(e) SET_ENVFLAGS(e, ENVFLAGS(e) & (~ FRAME_LOCK_MASK))

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool unlock_environment(Environment env) {
  UNLOCK_FRAME(env);
  return FRAME_IS_LOCKED(env) == 0;
}

/*** R
env <- new.env()
lockEnvironment(env)
try(env$a <- 1) ## error
unlock_environment(env)
env$a <- 1
*/
```

Calling `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` on a file with these contents gives me:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('~/scratch/unlock.cpp')

> env <- new.env()

> lockEnvironment(env)

> try(env$a <- 1) ## error
Error in env$a <- 1 : cannot add bindings to a locked environment

> unlock_environment(env)
[1] TRUE

> env$a <- 1 ## success!
```

The main little features here:

1. You can provide signatures using base / STL C++ types, or Rcpp types as well. Note that `bool` is the C++ bool type, and `Environment` is an Rcpp type encompassing environments.
2. Rcpp Attributes handles automatic conversion of these C++ return types to R's `SEXP`.

You might like Hadley's [`adv-r`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) introduction as well.

Comment: Nice post. The Rcpp Gallery, and Hadley's site are fine suggestion but there is actually a [vignette about Rcpp Attributes](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) as well.